# Multiple Date Range Filter

Tags: excel, excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have a spreadsheet that I'd like to be able to filter by multiple date ranges i.e. from 01-01-16/01-15-16, 01-16-16/02-01-16, 02-15-16/03-01-16, and so on.

I know that I could use the following in a calculated column while rinse and repeating for the different date ranges (changing the 1, 0 to some other indicator)...

```
=IIF(MyDate < '01-01-16' AND MyDate >= '01-15-16', 1, 0)
```

I was hoping that there was a better way to go about this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why is that way insufficient for your needs? And are the ranges sequential?

Comment: @Choirbean It isn't so much as insufficient, but I was wondering if there's a more efficient manner to go about this.

The date ranges are sequential as well, going from the 1st to 15th of each month and then 16th to last day of the month.

Comment: you could make up 24 columns of 1s and 0s and then filter based on which column you were interested in.  I think a better way would be to set your date range as two cells on your sheet, and then use your formula to point at those cells instead of hard coding the date.